# My domain does not work without "www" entered

Tags: dns

I have a domain that I'll called `example.com`. At this time,

```
| Entry                   | Result |
|-------------------------|--------|
| http://example.com      | Fails: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." |
| https://example.com     | Fails: 404 |
| http://www.example.com  | Succeeds   |
| https://www.example.com | Succeeds.  |
```

I believed that I setup my DNS records properly, however, after 48 hours, I'm still seeing the results above. My DNS records looks like this:

```
| Record Type | Name           | Value |
|-------------|----------------|-------|
| A           | @              | [ip address I get from running "ping www.example.com"] |
| CNAME       | calendar       | calendar.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | email          | email.secureserver.net | 
| CNAME       | fax            | fax.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | [someID]       | verify.bing.com |
| CNAME       | files          | files.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | ftp            | @ |
| CNAME       | imap           | imap.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | mail           | pop.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | mobilemail     | mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | pop            | pop.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | smtp           | smtp.secureserver.net |
| CNAME       | www            | jolly-dune-[id].azurestaticapps.net |
| CNAME       | _domainconnect | _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com |
| NS          | @              | pdns11.domaincontrol.com |
| NS          | @              | pdns12.domaincontrol.com |
```

Notably, when I run "ping www.example.com", I see the following repeated:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq ...
```

This doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of creating an A record, create a CNAME record that points to the same address as the "www" CNAME points to.

Comment: @SamForbis - I tried that. However, the `A` record requires an IP address. I cannot enter a domain name like the one used for the `www` `CNAME` record.

Comment: You could use `www  CNAME   @`.

Comment: @harrymc I'm sorry, but I think that's backwards, shouldn't it be `@ CNAME www`? I've also heard that you shouldn't necessarily point one `CNAME` to another because it causes the client to have to perform two lookups.

Comment: HTTP virtual hosting needs to be set up properly to know where to route requests. This does not appear to be the case, hence your problems.

Comment: @Dev I was not suggesting that you point your existing `A` record to that domain name, I was suggesting you delete that `A` record and create a new `@ CNAME` record.

Comment: Also, the “root” domain (`example.com`) cannot have a `CNAME` record, because it has to have `NS` records.

Comment: @DanielB My mistake. I guess I never had a situation where I needed to try that, so I never knew. Learn something new every day. I'm assuming that the OP is using an Azure-hosted site, and I was able to find this which may help out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain

Comment: Many dns providers allow root CNAME using tricks e.g. https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/ Cloudflare DNS is free and is a decent service even if you aren't using their CDN

Comment: @SamForbis Thank you for sharing. It sounds like the short-term fix is described [here](https://burkeholland.github.io/posts/static-app-root-domain/). Longer term, it sounds like Azure Static Web Apps is likely to support root domains.

Answer (score 0):

CNAME records are not allowed at the apex of your domain.

"A" records require an IP address.

As has been said, some hosting facilities play tricks to effectively allow you to add a CNAME record to the Apex.  It is generally called an Alias.

The easiest way I have found to solve this issue is to add an A record for the apex of your domain to "174.129.25.170".  [This website http://wwwizer.com/ does a naked redirect to "www" for free.](http://wwwizer.com/)

Essentially, it redirects your "example.com" request to "www.example.com" and it solves the issue very easily.

The next option is to create a redirect at the webserver level.  For Nginx, it would be something like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Another option is to switch hosting facilities to one that supports an alias.